# making subgroup aggregations in sql based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I’m trying to create sub-record aggregations from existing records in our data. 
Take this example data:

```
Index   Date    Action
1   1/1/2015    Working
2   1/2/2015    Working
3   1/3/2015    Working
4   1/4/2015    Escalated
5   1/5/2015    Done
6   1/6/2015    Working
7   1/7/2015    Done
8   1/8/2015    Working
9   1/9/2015    Working
10  1/10/2015   Working
11  1/11/2015   Escalated
12  1/12/2015   Done
13  1/13/2015   Done
14  1/14/2015   Working
```

I want to be able to create this data:

```
Record  DateBegin   DateEnd #Actions    #Escalations
A   1/1/2015        1/5/2015    5       1
B   1/6/2015        1/7/2015    2       0
C   1/8/2015        1/12/2015   5       1
D   1/13/2015       1/13/2015   1       0
E   1/14/2015       null        1       0
```

Basically, the logic is that a sub-record ends when the Action value = ‘Done’, and a new sub-record begins on any subsequent action (and also the very first action).
I am working with SQL Server 2008. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a grouping parameter by counting the number of `done` records before each record.  The rest is just aggregation, although assigning a letter for each group seems like unnecessary complication:

```
select grp as record, min(Date) as DateBegin,
       max(case when Action = 'Done' then Date end) as DateEnd,
       count(*) as NumActions,
       sum(case when Action = 'Escalation' then 1 else 0 end) as NumEscalations
from (select e.*, coalesce(e2.grp, 0) as grp
      from example e outer apply
           (select count(*) as grp
            from example e2
            where e2.id < e.id and e2.Action = 'Done'
           ) e2
     ) e
group by grp;
```

This query would be simpler (and more efficient) in SQL Server 2012+, which supports cumulative sums.

EDIT:

I notice that I use a subquery for this, but that is not necessary.  This can be written as:

```
      select coalesce(grp, 0) as record, min(Date) as DateBegin,
             max(case when Action = 'Done' then Date end) as DateEnd,
             count(*) as NumActions,
             sum(case when Action = 'Escalation' then 1 else 0 end) as NumEscalations
      from example e outer apply
           (select count(*) as grp
            from example e2
            where e2.id < e.id and e2.Action = 'Done'
           ) e2
      group by e2.grp
```

Comment: last record will not be in result:
"E   1/14/2015       null        1       0"

Comment: @parfilko . . . Why not?  It will have a `grp` value of "4" because there are 4 "done" records before it.  No other records will have a `grp` value of "4", so it will appear on its own row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - one issue I have is in my last group (most recent), if the last entry is not a 'done' entry, then I want to have 'null' as my DateEnd value for that group. Right now I'm always getting a date. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @csupak . . . That was definitely my mistake.  I misread the data structure as having a begin and end date.  The logic is simple enough using `date` and `action`.

Comment: that's what I mean :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Hi Gordon, one more issue - I'm trying to do this for multiple items. I'm nesting your solution as a table joined to another on a key value. Before I was just using one key value to test, but when I let it loose on all of the data, I'm getting weird results, or all null values. How would I provide the new key value for each item and get correct results for each item? I've tried adding e.keyVal = e2.keyVal to the where clause, and the query hasn't finished :) Is that the only way?

Comment: @csupak . . . That would be the right way.  The right indexes should improve performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - My results are still very wonky - a few rows get grossly inflated aggregations, while others get nulls that shouldn't. Somehow, the counting is not affixed to the appropriate item. Do I need another 'outer apply' when joining this to my set of initial records? I can start another question if that's appropriate.

Comment: @csupak . . . I was assuming that the ids are in order.  Although true for the data in your question, this might not be true for your actual data.  Does using the condition `and e2.date < e.date . . .` instead of `and e2.id < e.id` help?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - no, that gave me the same results. I went ahead and started another question that more clearly lays out the need to iterate over multiple items. Would you be able to look at it? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852499/making-multiple-subgroup-aggregations)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I made some progress - I added e.keyVal to my group by and that's helping, but the dates are off. Please see my new query if you get the chance, thanks! [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852499/making-multiple-subgroup-aggregations)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Try this, should work.

```
;with dones as (
    select
        nn = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [Date])
        ,*
    from YourTable
    where action = 'Done'

), ranges as (
    select
        [Record] = CHAR(ASCII('A') - 1 + ISNULL(d2.nn, d1.nn + 1))  --  A,B,C,... - after 255 will give NULL
        ,dtFrom = d1.[Date]
        ,dtTo = d2.[Date]
    from dones d1
    full join dones d2 on d1.nn = d2.nn + 1

)
    select 
        dones.[Record]
        ,DateBegin  = MIN(tt.[date]) 
        ,DateEnd = dones.dtTo
        ,[#Actions] = COUNT(tt.*)
        ,[#Escalations] = SUM(case when tt.Action = 'Escalated' then 1 else 0 end)
    from YourTable tt
    inner join dones 
        on (dones.dtFrom is null or tt.[date] > dones.dtFrom ) 
        and (dones.dtTo is null or tt.[date] <= dones.dtFrom)
    group by dones.[Record], dones.dtTo;
```

Comment: Using ranges rather than dones in the final select statement, I'm only returning `B B_BeginDate NULL 18 1`

Comment: yes, you right, there are some bugs - if you wish I can fix them. Anyway I like solution of Gordon Linoff