# making MULTIPLE subgroup aggregations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I’m trying to create sub-records with aggregations mined from existing records in our data. I have a table that lists records, with a one to many relationship to another that lists actions on each record. 
Record table looks like this:

```
Key  OpenDate  LastUpdate
aa   1/1/2015  1/14/2015
bb   1/3/2015  1/15/2015
```

Action table looks like this:

```
    Key  Date     Action
    aa  1/1/2015    Working
    aa  1/4/2015    Escalated
    aa  1/5/2015    Done
    aa  1/6/2015    Working
    aa  1/7/2015    Done
    aa  1/13/2015   Done
    aa  1/14/2015   Working
    bb  1/3/2015    Working
    bb  1/4/2015    Working
    bb  1/5/2015    Escalated
    bb  1/6/2015    Working
    bb  1/7/2015    Done
    bb  1/13/2015   Working
    bb  1/15/2015   Done
```

I want to be able to create a row for each time a record gets 'done' that notes the start and end of that cycle, and counts some items within that range:

```
Key  SubID  DateBegin   DateEnd   #Actions #Escalations
aa   1     1/1/2015    1/5/2015    3       1
aa   2     1/6/2015    1/7/2015    2       0
aa   3     1/13/2015   1/13/2015   1       0
aa   4     1/14/2015   null        1       0
bb   1     1/3/2015    1/7/2015    5       1
bb   2     1/13/2015   1/15/2015   2       0
```

Basically, the logic is that a sub-record ends when the Action value = ‘Done’, and a new sub-record begins on any subsequent action (and also the very first action).

I was shown a solution that works for only one record's data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781509/making-subgroup-aggregations-in-sql-based-on-a-column-value) , but more than one is giving me problems.
I am working with SQL Server 2008.

UPDATE -- I've got multiple records returning but the date data seems incorrect - not sure it's getting what it is supposed to:

```
SELECT Key, Cycles.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE, Cycles.CYCLE_END_DATE, Cycles.NUM_ACTIONS_IN_CYCLE
FROM Records
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (select e.Key, min(Date) as CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE,
          max(case when Action = 'Done') then Date end) as CYCLE_END_DATE,
          count(*) as NUM_ACTIONS_IN_CYCLE
    from (select Key, Action, rowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key ORDER BY Date asc), Date
     from Actions
   ) e
   outer apply
    (select count(*) as grp
        from (SELECT Key, rowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Reason_Key ORDER BY Date asc), Date, Action
    FROM Actions
   ) e2
   where e2.Date < e.Date and e2.Action = 'Done' and e.Reason_Key = e2.Reason_Key
   ) e2
   group by e.Reason_Key, e2.grp
) CYCLES
on Records.Key = Cycles.Key
```

Comment: Why does your previous question show an index column and this one doesn't in your action table? Has this table been updated since then?

Comment: @Rookie13 - I thought that would help communicate the need but it wasn't useful - the reality of what I need to do is better reflected here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think basically the same idea holds as in the earlier question.  You want to count the number of done record strictly before any given done record.  This gives you a group identifier that can then be used for aggregation.

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use the cumulative sum functionality.  In earlier versions, you can do the same thing with a correlated subquery or outer apply.

This version modifies your above in several ways.  In particular, it simplifies the logic of defining `grp`.  I don't easily see how `row_number()` fits into the query.  I do understand the logic -- enumerate the done actions and use that for aggregation.  But, getting that value on all the rows in the group is non-trivial.

```
SELECT r.Key, a.CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE, a.CYCLE_END_DATE, a.NUM_ACTIONS_IN_CYCLE
FROM Records r LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (select a.key, a2.grp, min(Date) as CYCLE_BEGIN_DATE,
             max(case when Action = 'Done') then Date end) as CYCLE_END_DATE,
             count(*) as NUM_ACTIONS_IN_CYCLE
      from actions a outer apply
           (select count(*) as grp
            from actions a2
            where a2.key = a.key and a2.date < a.date and a2.action = 'Done'
           ) a2
     group by a.key, a2.grp
    ) a
    on r.key = a.key;
```

Comment: great, yes, I don't know why I still had row_no in there. I needed to tweak yours to include the 'key' column in a. I also needed to add a.key to the group by, so that it would give correct results. But this does it, and it runs very quick - so happy, thanks